# Using JMF, How can I add a video to the background of a JPanel?

Tags: java, user-interface, video, jpanel, jmf

I am working on a GUI. It is strictly for Sign-in. I have it working perfectly, but I would like to add a video to the background of the Panel. Is there any way of doing this without having to make two separate JPanels? And if I had to use two, what would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why you would have to use two JPanels.  It seems like whatever JPanel contains your login that you want a video in the background you could just modify.  However, from a layout standpoint you might want the video as a separate component just to have more control and simpler code.